# C#: What would you name an IEnumerable class?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

When reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126256/net-collection-naming-convention) I started to wonder a bit. Say you have these two:

```
class ProductCollection : ICollection<Product>
class ProductList : IList<Product>
```

What would you call one that were an `IEnumerable<Product>`?

```
class Product--- : IEnumerable<Product>
```

Before I read that other question I might have called it a `ProductCollection` actually, but taking the new info into account, that would have been a bit misleading since it does not implement `ICollection<Product>`. Could you call it `Products`?

```
var products = new Products(); // products is/are products
```

Almost works but sounds a bit strange... What would you call it?

Comment: class ProductWhozitWhatzit { ... }

Comment: I have been trying to get ProductAmagig into a check-in for months

Comment: To be honest, it's personal preference / up to the senior dev. for naming conventions. I've never inherited from "IList<T>" before except for maybe one occasion (just recently). If I need a collection object, I'll just inherit from System.Collections.Generic.List<T>. For example: "public class PlayerList : List<Player> {"

Comment: @Zack: In that example of yours, personally I would probably end up with something different which had a List<Player>. For example a class Game with a List<Player> Players { get; } or something. Aanyways, off topic :p

Comment: @Svish: I create a whole object for itself because I can write indexers for them. Also, the PlayerList was a specific example from a project of mine that regulates a game server. "PlayerList" represents a collection of players in the server. :-P

Comment: Aha. But doesn't a List already have an indexer? And if you needed a different kind of indexer, for example string, I would think maybe a dictionary would be more fitting. Like if the key was a players name for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You generally do not base the name of a class off any *interface* it implements. (Which one do you choose when there are multiple ones, for a start?) It is quite typical to base it off an *inherited class*, but more often simply on the purpose of the class, and certainly not the interface. (The interface might be named after the class, if anything.)

Your example is somewhat invalidated by the fact that a well-designed `ProductCollection` should implement `ICollection<Product>` *and* `IEnumerable<Product>` while a well-designed `ProductList` should implement both those interfaces as well as `IList<Product>`.

If you look in the BCL of the .NET Framework, you should notice that this is precisely the case. The `List<T>` class implements all three interfaces, as does the `Collection<T>` class (though note that in the general case a 'collection' need not implement `IList<T>`).

Comment: @Svish: Glad it helped. The BCL is a generally good model to go by here (though it may contain the odd inconsistency). So long as you have consistency in your own class names, you can't go far wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I think that "Sequence" would be a good suffix.

Comment: Was thinking about that one as well actually.

Comment: Indeed. The above posters have not considered that the list of items may be generated dynamically rather than being backed by an actual list or array of some kind.

Answer (score 5):

If it only implements `IEnumerable<Product>`, then I would name it `ProductEnumeration`, but I would feel free to name an instance of it `products`.  On the other hand, I don't recall ever creating a class that only implemented `IEnumerable<T>`.  Doesn't seem to be much point if you can't add stuff to it and if you can, then I'd derive from one of the collection classes that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and inherit that behavior, too.

If I were returning an enumeration of Product entities, I'd simply return it as `IEnumerable<Product>` without having a special class.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend upon the context, for example, it could be a `ProductsCatalog` (implying the read-only nature of `IEnumerable`).

More generally, it could be `ProductsView`. Of course, the `Products` fetched would be modifiable, but I feel it "sounds" appropriate nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that List or Collection impose they behave that way. But IEnumerable is very generic, not only in the C# meaning of generic. Every implementation can be behind it.

Some suggestions:

- ProductIterator: This iterates Products.
- ProductRetriever: This retrieves Products.
- ProductCreator: This creates new Products at runtime.

Comment: I wouldn't call it `ProductIterator`. If you implement `IEnumerable`, there's a `GetEnumerator` method that returns an `IEnumerator` which is the actual iterator.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the types in the .NET Framework that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, I would say that the most common suffix is `Collection`, followed by the plural form of what the list contains. Then there are a number of "special cases" (such as `Queue` and `Stack`). I would personally vote for `Collection` as a first-hand choice.

Answer (score 0):

In almost every case I can think of from my own experience, I haven't had to think of a name. The compiler does it for me, because I write an iterator method instead of writing a class by hand. And for the method name, it seems natural to just make it a plural word describing the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Like kek444 I think I'd have to ask what else does it do? It implements IEnumerable<> but that's not all it does, or else you wouldn't need the class right? It is a collection? Does it transform one enumerable to another (alter order, selection, generation, etc)?

Answer (score -1):

I would say *Collection*. It might suggest a ReadOnlyCollection or ObservableCollection , but it describes the class well. It is after all a collection of products (whatever the underlying type may be).

To solve this question and the other question, use this ;)
http://www.classnamer.com/