# How to name C# List<T> type variable/object according to MicroSoft naming guidelines?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

I want to give my variable/object name of type List for e.g. I have a class Position but I am confuse with which one is proper name PositionList or ListPosition or only Positions ??

Can anyone help me for the same ??

Thanks & regards
Rudresh Bhatt

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Collection Naming Convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126256/net-collection-naming-convention)