# How to name an entity class that represents a collection of key/value pairs

Tags: c#, .net, orm, naming-conventions, naming

We have an existing relational database table named `Preference` that we cannot reasonably change with the following schema:

```
| PreferenceId | UserId | SerializedValue |
```

Each `SerializedValue` represents a serialized (custom format, space-delimited) collection of key/value pairs. (The set of keys is determined by `PreferenceId`.)

We are trying to model this with typed entities in our application. We have landed on something like below, where we have a unique `Derived<ClassName>` for each `PreferenceId`.

```
public class <ClassName> {
    public int PreferenceId { get; set; }
    public string SerializedValue { get; set; }
}

public class Derived<ClassName> : <ClassName> {
    /*
    properties whose names represent the keys
    and whose values represent the values
    when SerializedValue is deserialized
    */
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public int Key2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Question:**
What is a good name for `<ClassName>`?

Options we've considered:

- `Preference` - This aligns best with the database schema, but doesn't make conceptual sense since each key/value pair in `SerializedValue` is really a "preference" by itself, so the class represents a collection of preferences.
- `Preferences` - It is generally bad practice to make a class name plural.
- `PreferenceCollection` - Consensus for similar problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1126256/2343739), but tends to imply that the class contains an actual collection property, which it does not.
- `PreferenceDictionary` - Suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126292/2343739). Indicates key/value pairs, which it has; but also indicates a .NET dictionary type, which it is not.